# Save is not performing in Spring Mvc 3Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

`Article` class:

```
package net.devmanuals.model;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "imei")
    public class Article {
    @Id
        @Column(name = "imei1",nullable = false)
    private Long imeiNo;
        @Column(name = "date_added")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date addedDate;

    public Article() {      
    }

        public Long getimei1() {
        return imeiNo;
    }

    public void setimei1(Long imei1) {
        this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
    }

        public Date getAddedDate() {
        return addedDate;
    }

    public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }   
}
```

`ArticleController` class:

```
package net.devmanuals.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.devmanuals.model.Article;
import net.devmanuals.service.ArticleService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article,
            BindingResult result) {
         articleService.addArticle( article);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listArticles() {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("articles",  articleService.listArticles());

        return new ModelAndView("articlesList", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,
            BindingResult result) {
        return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
    }

}
```

`Article` service:

```
package net.devmanuals.service;

import java.util.List;

import net.devmanuals.model.Article;

public interface ArticleService {

    public void addArticle(Article article);

    public List<Article> listArticles();
}
```

This Error comes when saving data,(But no error while displaying data):

```
exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): net.devmanuals.model.Article
    root cause
 org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): net.devmanuals.model.Article
```

Comment: There is too much code, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You need an Id generation scheme. Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997494/ids-for-this-class-must-be-manually-assigned-before-calling-save

Comment: Sir i have added  @GeneratedValue but know some other error comes. Sir actually i want to insert the imei(i.e id manually not autogenerated)

Comment: @MrD i thought it will clear my problem , so thats why i have posted 3 classes

Comment: Please Help me to enter Id manually and save data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all. You must assign an ID to your entity before persisting it. So just call a method that sets the value of `imeiNo` before calling `persist()`. Unfortunately, you don't have any such method. The only one that looks like such a setter is the following one:

```
public void setimei1(Long imei1) {
    this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
}
```

But, not only is it badly named (it should be called `setImeiNo`), but it also has an obvious bug: it completely ignores its argument, and sets the value of `imeiNo` to the value it already has.

Given the mess that your getters and setters are, my advice would be:

- remove them all
- use your IDE to regenerate them automatically

The setter should be:

```
public void setImeiNo(Long imeiNo) {
    this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks too all and i will try to do that you all have told then reply you,, thanksss

Comment: Thanks to all , actually it was my mistake,, you are right sir @JB Nizet   .my error was                                            public void setimei1(Long imei1) {
    this.imeiNo = imeiNo;
}

Comment: But Sir i want to display the time also when the date display. In my database Date and time is shown but not in Browser, Please tell me how to get time also?

Comment: If you want to have date and time, don't you think TemporalType.TIMESTAMP would be more appropriate than TemporalType.DATE?

Comment: Sir can you tell me that how to enter value in two database at one time?? because i have to enter imei number in one table and imei and date and time in second table. i have perform working of second table but i didnt know how to enter values at one time in two tables. Pleae help if you can

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, i am talking about two tables. i will edit it. ok sir

Comment: And i will enter new Question also.. Thankss Sir

Answer (score 0):

put to you model an it that is to be autoincremented automatically and you should not see the error and will not need to add the id yourself

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: Thanks to @MatthiasLaug , But actually i need to add id(i.e imei no) manually. Still thanks